# Outer DIV not shrink-wrapping

Tags: html, css, position

I have display inline-block etc. but the htmlDiv div in this mark-up does not behave as I expected.  It behaves as if the inner divs are beside each other even when they are not.  How to fix this?

Please run the animated snippet if it's not clear...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```js
var demoContainer = d3.select('#demoContainer').style('width', '100px')
    function tick() {
      demoContainer.transition().duration(4000).style('width', '400px')
      .transition().duration(4000).style('width', '600px')
      .transition().duration(3000).style('width', '400px')
      .transition().duration(3000).style('width', '100px')
      .each('end', tick);
    };
    tick();
```

```css
#htmlDiv {
      font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Segoe UI', Arial, freesans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;    
  outline: solid 1px black;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }

    .container {
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }

    .bubbles,
    .subBubbles,
    .span {
      color: #ccc;
    }

    .select-bubbles,
    .bubbles {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 3px;
      outline: solid 1px white;
      background-color: rgb(114, 114, 114);
      width: 150px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="demoContainer" style="outline: solid 3px red; padding: 10px">
    <div id="htmlDiv">
      I want this outer div to shrink-wrap the 4 inner divs regardless of width... <br>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="select-bubbles">
          <select class="selector">
            <option value="select">select</option>
            <option value="selectAll">selectAll</option>
          </select>
          <select id="multi-single">
            <option value="4">multi</option>
            <option value="1">single</option>
          </select>
          <div class="select-subBubbles">
            <select class="selector">
              <option value="select">select</option>
              <option value="selectAll" selected="selected">selectAll</option>
            </select>
            <span class="select-spans">
              <select class="selector">
                <option value="select">select</option>
                <option value="selectAll">selectAll</option>
              </select>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> <br>
      <div class="bubbles bubble1">
        bubble1
        <div class="subBubbles bubble1">
          <span>sub1</span>
          <span class="spans bubble1">
            <span style="transform: rotateX(0deg); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" class="temp">
              sub1
            </span> subsub1
          </span>
          <span class="spans bubble2">subsub2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="subBubbles bubble2">
          <span>
            sub2
          </span>
          <span class="spans bubble1">
            <span class="temp">
              sub2
            </span>
            subsub1
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bubbles bubble2">
        bubble2
        <div class="subBubbles bubble1">
          sub1
          <span class="spans bubble1">subsub1</span>
          <span class="spans bubble2">subsub2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="subBubbles bubble2">
          sub2
          <span class="spans bubble1">subsub1</span>
          <span class="spans bubble2">subsub2</span>
        </div><div class="subBubbles bubble3">
          sub3
          <span class="spans bubble1">
            subsub1
          </span>
          <span class="spans bubble2">
            subsub2
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bubbles bubble2">
        bubble2
        <div class="subBubbles bubble1">
          sub1
          <span class="spans bubble1">subsub1</span>
          <span class="spans bubble2">subsub2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="subBubbles bubble2">
          sub2
          <span class="spans bubble1">subsub1</span>
          <span class="spans bubble2">subsub2</span>
        </div><div class="subBubbles bubble3">
          sub3
          <span class="spans bubble1">
            subsub1
          </span>
          <span class="spans bubble2">
            subsub2
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's really not clear what the issue is here. What is this **supposed** to look like or behave? Of course, it's possible your interpretation of "shrink wrap" is incorrect.

Comment: @Paulie_D shrink-wrap means the outer div's inner dimensions are constrained by the outer dimensions of the inner elements.  So the distance between the outlines of the inner and outer elements is the margin of the inner box and the padding of the outer box.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with your were you were setting width for 250px in the below code

```
.select-bubbles, .bubbles {
     padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  outline: solid 1px white;
  background-color: rgb(114, 114, 114);
  /* width: 250px; */
  /* display: inline-block; */
 }
```

Remove the inline-block and setting your width to 250px which causes your box not to shrink less than 250px.

We are removing the inline-block for the time being if u want u can add it with some more properties to make it look good.

Comment: you are talking about the inner elements, there is no width constraint on the outer box which is called htmlDiv.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but I think you want to do the following:

```
.container,
.select-bubbles,
.bubbles {
    display: block;
}
```

Instead of `inline-block`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that stops the divs from flowing properly as per my updated question...